# Can't change Char

Tags: java, android, char

When I'm trying to change char in my word when I click on for example button A. I want a set char on A and change in my invisible word from (--) set A there where is his position. I'm generating code in NetBeans.

```
if(hadanka.contains(pismeno))
{
    for(int i=0;i!=hadanka.length();i++)
    if(pismeno.equals(Character.toString(hadanka.charAt(i))))
    {
        prepsani[i]=hadanka.charAt(i);

    }

    System.out.println(prepsani);;
}
```

Everything is ok. Hadanka is a guessing word and pismeno is the letter that I chose.
When I use it in my application for Android errors occur.

Here is my Android code:

```
char zvolenePismeno;
public void OnStart (View v)

{
    if(odpoved.contains(zvolenePismeno))
    {
        for(int i=0;i!=odpoved.length();i++)
        if(zvolenePismeno.equals(Character.toString(odpoved.charAt(i))))
        {
            prepsani[i]=odpoved.charAt(i);

        }
        labOdpoved.setText(String.valueOf(prepsani));
    }

}

public void OnA(View v)
{
    zvolenePismeno = 'A';
    kliknuti(btn_A);
}
```

The errors I get is the following:

> the method contains(charsequence) in the type string is not applicable
>   for the arguments (char)

at the line `if(odpoved.contains(zvolenePismeno))` and

> cannot invoke equals (String) on the primitive type char

at the line `if(zvolenePismeno.equals(Character.toString(odpoved.charAt(i))))`.

### UPDATE 1

it is doesn't work :/ Im change my code on

```
 if(odpoved!=null)
         {
               for(int i=0;i!=odpoved.length();i++)
                    if(zvolenePismeno==odpoved.charAt(i))
                      {
                           prepsani[i]=odpoved.charAt(i);

                      } 
               labOdpoved.setText(String.valueOf(prepsani));
         }
```

Here is my whole code (with error )¨

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    int lvl1;
    String[] Level1 = {"APPLE", "SAMSUNG", "NOKIA", "HTC"};
    String odpoved, pokus;
    char zvolenePismeno;

    public void OnStart(View v) {
        btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        labOdpoved = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labOdpoved);
        Random rand = new Random();
        lvl1 = Math.abs(rand.nextInt() % 3);
        odpoved = Level1[lvl1];

        char[] prepsani = new char[odpoved.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i != odpoved.length(); i++) {
            prepsani[i] = '-';
        }
        labOdpoved.setText(String.valueOf(prepsani));
        if (odpoved.contains(zvolenePismeno)) {
            for (int i = 0; i != odpoved.length(); i++)
                if (zvolenePismeno.equals(Character.toString(odpoved.charAt(i)))) {
                    prepsani[i] = odpoved.charAt(i);
                }
            labOdpoved.setText(String.valueOf(prepsani));
        }
    }

    public void kliknuti(Button btn) {
        btn.setClickable(false);
        btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    public void OnA(View v) {
        zvolenePismeno = 'A';
        btn_A = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_A);
        kliknuti(btn_A);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update with your LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

**char != Char**
 Class **Char** has method **equals**  but not primitive type **char**.

```
if (odpoved!=null) 
 for(int i=0;i!=odpoved.length();i++) 
   if (zvolenePismeno==odpoved.charAt(i))
```

Should work

Comment: Ares do you know what can i do with that ?

Comment: line
 if (odpoved.contains(zvolenePismeno)) {
is unnecessary.
But You leave it in  whole code